# Is there a way of referencing a cell in Pluto.jl

Tags: julia, markdown, pluto.jl

I'm writing a Pluto notebook and would like to make something like the following cells:

Cell 1:

```
"""md
## Index
1. [`Section 1`](##Section 1) 
"""
```

Cell 2:

```
"""md
## Section 1

A bunch of text...
"""
```

The first cell generates a index with a link, but I can't get the link to work for referencing another cell in the notebook; in the Julia docs I only found this https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/stdlib/Markdown/#Links, but it seems this is only for documentation. Maybe this is not supported yet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is what you can do (tested with Pluto):

Cell 1:

```
md"""[Link](#hello)"""
```

Cell 2:

```
md"""### Hello!!!"""
```

Cell 3 (actual anchor):

```
html"""<a class="anchor" id="hello"></a>"""
```

If all your objects are markdown headers you can `using PlutoUI` automatically generate a table of contents simply having a following cell:

```
TableOfContents()
```

[image]